# AIX : /etc/security/limits file Parameters

Tags: security, aix, ulimit

Can anybody please explain about following parameters found /etc/security/limits file

```
default:
    fsize = 2097151
    core = 2097151
    cpu = -1
    data = 262144
    rss = 65536
    stack = 65536
    nofiles = 2000
```

Comment: Have you read the man page for `/etc/security/limits`? What parts specifically are unclear to you?

Answer (score 3):

They are described quite well in the [standard AIX documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.files/limits.htm).

- **fsize :**  Identifies the soft limit for the largest file a user's process can create or extend.
- **core :**   Specifies the soft limit for the largest core file a user's process can create.
- **cpu :**    Sets the soft limit for the largest amount of system unit time (in seconds) that a user's process can use.
- **data :**   Identifies the soft limit for the largest process data segment for a user's process.
- **stack :**  Specifies the soft limit for the largest process stack segment for a user's process.
- **rss :**    Sets the soft limit for the largest amount of physical memory a user's process can allocate. This limit is not enforced by the system.
- **nofiles :**    Sets the soft limit for the number of file descriptors a user process may have open at one time.

The 'default' stanza means they're applied to all users who do not have a more specific entry.